# Determining the neutral axis of an I-shaped cross section with dissimilar materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics, moment-of-inertia

Determine the neutral axis of the  I- shaped cross section with dissimilar materials.

The top rectangle of the cross section is made out of aluminum and the second and third part are titanium ( these are respectively the rectangle that connects the upper and lower part and the lower rectangle itself ).

I do not think the dimensions are needed since I only want to find out in what way this has to be solved.

How do I regard the difference in materials in this case? I have never done this before and could not find anything useful on the site nor the internet.

Kenny

Comment: Are the parts fixed together, or can they slide past each other. This makes a difference in the resulting strain distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The shape has to share strain across the cross section. If the centroid is at $y=0$ then assume linear strain in the section of the form $\epsilon(y) = C_0 + C_1 y$ which would yield a neutral axis at $y_0 = -\frac{C_0}{C_1}$. Make material [1] the `Ti` and material [2] the `Al` with top and bottom bar width $w$, overall height $h$ and thickness $t$.

The stresses on the two materials are $\sigma_1(y) = E_1 \epsilon(y)$ and $\sigma_2(y) = E_2 \epsilon(y)$. Now we integrate the stress over the area to get internal force and moment.

$$ F = \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{-\frac{h}{2}+t} w \sigma_1 \,{\rm d}y + \int_{-\frac{h}{2}+t}^{\frac{h}{2}-t} t \sigma_1 \,{\rm d}y + \int_{\frac{h}{2}-t}^{\frac{h}{2}} w \sigma_2 \,{\rm d}y $$
 $$ M = \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{-\frac{h}{2}+t} w\,y \sigma_1 \,{\rm d}y + \int_{-\frac{h}{2}+t}^{\frac{h}{2}-t} t\,y \sigma_1 \,{\rm d}y + \int_{\frac{h}{2}-t}^{\frac{h}{2}} w\,y \sigma_2 \,{\rm d}y $$

For pure bending we have $F=0$ and $M\ne 0$ yielding some rather lengthy expressions for $C_0$ and $C_1$. But we only need the ratio

$$ y_0 = -\frac{C_0}{C_1} = \frac{ \frac{h-t}{2} ( E_1 - E_2 ) }{ E_1 \left( \frac{h}{w} \left( \frac{2 t}{h}-1 \right)-1\right)-E_2} $$

I would like to confirm this value with an FEA before using it anywhere.

<sup>NOTE:</sup>I used CAS software to do the integrals and simplification.

<sup>ADDENDUM:</sup> You can set the applied moment, to be an eccentric axial load with $M=z\,F$ and then find for what values of $z$ the neutral axis goes to infinity (pure axial elongation). It turns out that $z=y_0$, confirming that a load through the neutral axis yields pure axial deformation (similar to a load through the a center of mass yields a pure translation).

Comment: I get the answer: $$y_0=\frac{(w\,t+h^2-2\,h\,t)E_1+(2\,w\,h-w\,t)E_2}{2\left((w+h-2\,t)E_1+w\,E_2\right)}$$
Also it might be more convenient to write $\epsilon(y)=C(y-y_0)$.

Comment: Never mind, I choose $y=0$ at the bottom of the I-beam, while you placed it in the middle of the I-beam.

Answer (score 0):

For a section with different materials, you need to transform the section into a section of one material. The way to do it is to first get the Young's modulus $E$ of the different materials. For your problem, let's say that the modulus of aluminum is $E_a$, and the modulus of titanium is $E_t$. You may then proceed in either of the following ways. If the section is transformed into aluminum, then the widths of the second and third rectangles should be multiplied by a factor of $E_t/E_a$. If, otherwise, the section is transformed into titanium, then the width of the first rectangle should be multiplied by a factor of $E_a/E_t$. The neutral axis is at the geometric centroid of the transformed section.

Comment: Note that a bi-metalic part will bend under axial load, and stretch under bending. Modeling it as an equivalent youngs modulus is not going to be accurate. This method can only work with symmetric cross sections that are axially loaded only (like overhead power lines).